# Range error with ClosedXML file save

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I am modifying an existing Excel file with ClosedXML.  Everything works great right up until I save the file:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.\r\nParameter name: The cells A4 and X3 are outside the range 'Delinquency!A3:X3'.
>
> at ClosedXML.Excel.XLRangeBase.GetRange(XLAddress newFirstCellAddress,
>   XLAddress newLastCellAddress)
>
> at ClosedXML.Excel.XLRangeBase.Range(IXLCell firstCell, IXLCell
>   lastCell)
>
> at ClosedXML.Excel.XLRange.ClosedXML.Excel.IXLRange.Range(IXLCell
>   firstCell, IXLCell lastCell)
>
> at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.PopulateAutoFilter(XLAutoFilter
>   xlAutoFilter, AutoFilter autoFilter)
>
> at
>   ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.GenerateWorksheetPartContent(WorksheetPart
>   worksheetPart, XLWorksheet xlWorksheet, Boolean evaluateFormulae,
>   SaveContext context)
>
> at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.CreateParts(SpreadsheetDocument
>   document, SaveOptions options)
>
> at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.CreatePackage(String filePath,
>   SpreadsheetDocumentType spreadsheetDocumentType, SaveOptions options)
>
> at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.SaveAs(String file, SaveOptions options)
>
> at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.SaveAs(String file, Boolean validate,
>   Boolean evaluateFormulae)at
>   ST_6bc5fa72e8174cd4a207b1b253d87b23.ScriptMain.Main() in
>   c:\Users\jdoe\AppData\Local\Temp\Vsta\48f142323f754c1487ca867a1cf952c5\ScriptMain.cs:line
>   279

Every bit of code I have that uses ClosedXML is below:

```
cx.XLWorkbook doc = new cx.XLWorkbook(docName);
cx.IXLWorksheet ws = doc.Worksheet(sheetname);

ws.SelectedRanges.Clear();
doc.SaveAs(docName, false);

private static int FindRow(cx.IXLWorksheet worksheet, string findText)
{
  int result = -1;
  cx.IXLRows usedrange = (cx.IXLRows)worksheet.RowsUsed();
  string address = string.Empty;
  foreach (cx.IXLRow row in usedrange)
  {
    int rowval = row.RangeAddress.FirstAddress.RowNumber;
    cx.IXLCell cell = worksheet.Cell(rowval, 3);
    if (cell.Value.ToString() == findText)
    {
       result = rowval;
       break;
    }
  }
  usedrange = null;
  return result;
}

private static string FindValue(cx.IXLWorksheet worksheet, int columnName, int rowval)
{
  string returnval = string.Empty;
  cx.IXLCell fcell = worksheet.Cell(rowval, columnName);
  if (fcell != null)
    returnval = fcell.Value.ToString();
  return returnval;
}

private static void ReplaceValue (cx.IXLWorksheet worksheet, string replaceText, int columnName, int rowval)
{
   cx.IXLCell rcell = worksheet.Cell(rowval, columnName);
   rcell.Value = replaceText;
}
```

The sheet name is indeed Delinquency, and its relevant data to be searched starts at row 3 and does go through column X.  But why on earth is this error showing up when I save the file?

(The clearing of SelectedRanges and setting usedRange to null are both things I've attempted to get the file to save properly.)

I've also opened the source file up in the OpenXML validator, just to make sure the file itself doesn't have an issue that is causing this problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I thought maybe my laziness had betrayed me, as I used the same name for the IXLCell in all three methods, but renaming them made no difference. (The code above has been edited to show the current variable names, which are not all "cell".)

Comment: Log it as a bug on github